# Why JDBC driver call works in Tomcat but not in JBOSS

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, jboss, connection

I have an application that makes a connection to a database via Tomcat using the following method in the `DriverManager`

```
DriverManager.getConnection(url, user,password);
```

This works fine **in Tomcat** with no issues at all.

But when I port this same application to **JBOSS**, the connection is always returning `NULL`.

I have some requirements that will prevent me from making the JDBC connection by accessing a JNDI resource using `DriverManager.getConnection(url)`;

Does anyone know why this happens and or how I can get around it?

Here is the stack trace I receive.....

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:419)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:536)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:228)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
    at TestSterlingConnection.getStrelingDBDetails(TestSterlingConnection.java:48)
    at TestSterlingConnection.makeCall(TestSterlingConnection.java:95)
    at TestSterlingConnection.doGet(TestSterlingConnection.java:77)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably because an appropriate JDBC driver is not on your classpath. The drivers now register themselves automatically using the `ServiceLoader` (META-INF/services) mechanism. So it just needs to be on the classpath. `DriverManager.getConnection` scans the registered drivers to find one that matches the url pattern (ie oracle, postgres, whatever). Your Tomcat instance probably has a jdbc jar file in one of the lib directories.

Comment: I believe you are correct since the jdbc jar file is in the lib directory located in the war file that I am deploying.  Do you know where I should place the jar file?  I understand that JBOSSPATH/lib shouldn't be modified.

Comment: Not familiar with JBOSS, but a search on "installing jdbc drivers on JBOSS" finds links like [this](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/apbs02.html) which suggest placing the driver here: jboss-as/server/<env>/lib You can also take a look at the Encoder example in [ServiceLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) to create a bean to loop through all the registered drivers and log what it finds. Then you know what is there and what is not.

Comment: And actually the driver was already in the appconfig/lib folder so the driver isn't the problem.

Comment: I added the stack trace which shows that the drivers have already been found.

Comment: Is it the same version of the Driver? JDBC4 drivers are the ones that are able to register themselves.

Comment: Okay, yes, you have the driver. Now it is a connection issue. So you will need to check if you can ping, telnet, are the ports open, credentials correct, ...

Comment: yes I'm able to ping and the ports are open because there are other applications on the same server that access the database that I'm trying to access.

Answer (score 0):

I have eliminated JBOSS by executing the same call on this box outside of the container.  When I do this I get the same error message which leads me to believe this issue is caused by some Network Configuration.  I am now escalating to the administrators responsible for maintaining this server.

Thank you so much!!  I really appreciate your help glen.